# How does scipy.stats.distributions.fit works?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I was trying to approximate some hard distribution with normal one. But `scipy.stats.norm.fit` gives some awkward results. Approximational result is very far from original. Then I have tried manually set parameters and it looks far more better. However, loglikelihood states, then `metod` is better.
Why? Does everything work correctly? Are there other ways to estimate parameters of distribution?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
domain = np.linspace(0,1,100)
import math


def f(x):
    return 100 / 0.5 * 0.5 ** 50 / (math.factorial(49)) * (100 *x / 0.5) ** 49 * np.exp(-(100 * x / 0.5 ) / 2)

data = [f(x) for x in domain]
plt.plot(domain, data, label = 'orig')

params = norm.fit(data)
plt.plot(domain, norm.pdf(domain, *params), label = 'approx_fit')
plt.plot(domain, norm.pdf(domain, 0.495, 0.07), label = 'approx_manual')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
print(f'LLH by fitting with scipy.stats.norm.fit : {norm.logpdf(data, *params).sum()}')
new_params = (0.495, 0.07)
print(f'LLH by manually founded parameters : {norm.logpdf(data, *new_params).sum()}')
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you are calling `norm.fit()` with the data points of a pdf curve, while in reality it is meant to be called with sample data.

Comment: For your case, if you know the parametric form of the desired pdf, calling [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) could be more appropriate.